# Attribute is missing the android namespace prefix, can't find error

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

```
<linearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainDrawingActivity" >

</linearLayout>
```

I can't figure out what's missing... help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's LinearLayout, not linearLayout. Capitalize your L.

Comment: ahh, and now I feel slightly embarrassed... Thank you!

Comment: use an IDE like Android Studio, it autocompletes things like this.

Comment: I'm using eclipse with the android plug-in as that was what google recommended, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Android development is moving to Android Studio and I would recommend using it. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html